# Entity Framework - Error: define the key for entity type

Tags: entity-framework

Hallo everybody,

i have the following simple models.

```
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }

}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

I get an error while i am trying to get the data:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: :
>   EntityType 'A' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.

Previous it was done via "RelatedTo". Has anybody a solution for this problem with the help of an example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entity in EF must have a primary key. It looks like A is junction table for many to many so you have multiple choices.

Remove A totaly and let EF handle many-to-many:

```
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

If you want A as entity you must either define additional key:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}
```

or you must include FK properties for B and C and mark them both as composite primary key (should be in db as well):

```
public class A
{
    public int bId { get; set; }
    public int cId { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

Mapping for the last solution

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>.HasKey(a => new { a.bId, a.cId });
modelBuilder.Entity<A>.HasRequired(a => a.B)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(a => a.bId);
modelBuilder.Entity<A>.HasRequired(a => a.C)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(a => a.cId);
```

Anyway if your A looks exactly as you described without any other properties you are definitely doing it wrong. Mapping A is only needed when it contains anything else then navigation properties / FKs for modelling many-to-many relation.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. But if i add an additional key or new properties, then i will get an error when i am trying to get the data e.g. using toList(). How can i mark them as "composite primaray key" so they are excluded?

Comment: That is not only about adding properties - these properties must be mapped to database columns (= they must exists in database as well) - they cannot be excluded. What version of EF are you using and what type of mapping are you using?

Comment: EF Version is 4.0.30319. I use "WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("Id"));" where Id is the fk of B and the same for the id of c. If i add two new ids i can't map them to the same ids.

Comment: Why don't you use the first example? Creating entity for junction table is not needed.

Comment: we are using code first and we need the third solution. Can you explain the third solution in more detail, or do you have an example?

Comment: hi thanks for the example, the problem is, i can't change the database because it already exists... so i have to do it like this